# SQL - replace one value with another from another table with priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - **replacement products**

| product_id | priority | qty_total | qty_used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00502 | 1 | 0 | 1000 |
| 00520 | 2 | 500 | 500 |
| 00528 | 3 | 1200 | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

And **orders** with (possible) products to-be-replaced (product 500)

| cust_id | order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 500 |
| 1 | 0001 | 500 |
| 1 | 0001 | 507 |
| 1 | 0002 | 500 |
| 2 | 0003 | 627 |
| 2 | 0003 | 525 |

I want to change the product in each new order where is the product 500 to another product from the table with replacement products, but it needs to fulfill qty_total>qty_used condition, there shouldn't be any same replacements in the same order and the products that are replacements should replace based on their priority.

It should look like this.

| cust_id | order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 502 |
| 1 | 0001 | 520 |
| 1 | 0001 | 507 |
| 1 | 0002 | 502 |
| 2 | 0003 | 627 |
| 2 | 0003 | 525 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do mention what have you tried so far

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.